# css background static?

Tags: css

if i wanted a background that deosnt move(stays static) so only the page moves when scrolling, if you get what i mean!!

this is my background code:

```
 background: #fff url(back1.png) ;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you're using the shorthand `background` property, just add `fixed` to the end of the rule:

```
background: #fff url(back1.png) fixed;
```

This is actually the `background-attachment` property, so if you expand it out it's this:

```
background-color: #fff;
background-image: url(back1.png);
background-attachment: fixed;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add:

> ```
> background-attachment: fixed;
> ```